# call component two from component one and pass data from component one

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have two components component1(showing a list of items), component2(showing item details), component2 is hidden by default. 
 
i want : when a user click on a list item in component2, the component2 should show the details for the selected item.
For this i created a shared service, the service shares data and works fine
my problem is: 
1: how do I make component2 aware of click events on component1, so that it loads the details for clicked item after user clicked an item on list view.
2: component 2 is hidden using *ngIf="isComponent2Visible", how can i show it after a user click on an item in component1(listview).
I hope the question is easy to understand and good structured.

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: the code is pretty long, i have to cut the irrelevant once later, i will paste it if i do not get a good suggestion here.   if i do not get a solution i will post the code after a few hours.

Comment: Sure thing, it just usually attracts more answers when there is code to look at, like highly suggested by SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .. instead of trying to guess how your code looks like. But yes, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using `*ngIf` as you did. Just call a function when item is clicked and pass its item Id like `(click)="display(item.id)"` set this Id to component property so that you can access it in your template.

Component

```
displayItemId: number = 0;

display(id:number){
   this.displayItemId = id;
}
```

HTML

```
<display-component *ngIf="displayItemId>0" [displayItemId]="displayItemId"></display-component>
```

And in your display component use this `@Input() displayItemId` to get specific details in `ngOnInit()` function.

OR If you want to use the current item or already fetched details in your first component then pass whole item as input and use it on second component's template.

Component

```
displayItem: any;

display(item:any){
   this.displayItem = item;
}
```

HTML

```
<display-component *ngIf="displayItem" [displayItem]="displayItem">
```

Other (recommended) approach is to use router. Just navigate to a URL containing Id `items/details/5`, get Id from route in your second component and use it to fetch details.

Comment: i do that, i use @Input()  to get the displayitemId. my problem is i do not want to show the details after component initialisation (ngOnInit()) but after the user clicked on an item on component1.

Comment: Check my updated answer if you want something like this?

Comment: <component2 *ngIf="displayItem" ></component2> .  at load time displayitem is set to false. later on in my service i set the displayItem to true, it do not updates the view, so i want to update the view when the displayItem is set to true (i.e when the displayitem is true the component2 should become visible

Comment: i can not use router as i already use <router-outlet> for other purposes

Comment: If you are setting this in service then use EventEmitter to emit changes from service and subscribe/listen in your component1 and update the displayItem, this way updated displayItem will pass to your component2.

Comment: i think i am looking for some thing like this, i will post my code if it did not helped me . https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

Comment: Also check this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html

Comment: Thanks for the kind answers, I managed to get what i want with defining observable and subscribing to them in second component. i will post detailed solution in weekend. Appreciate your answers.